# IBActions in class extensions

Tags: ios, xcode4

Is there a clean way to put IBActions in class extensions (without linking them to IB in .h, then moving to class extension in .m)?

I can link or create the IBActions in IB, and them cut and paste them to the class extension in the .m.  Is there a way to create them directly in the class extension from IB?

Thanks

Comment: by the way, if my answer worked for you, please mark it as the solution by clicking the checkmark on the left, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this and it works for me. What does your class extension look like? It should look like this:

```
@interface MyClass ()
- (IBAction)myAction:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: Yes.. you can type them in the extension, or cut and paste them to the extension.. but how do you get them to link in the IB with something in the extension (or create the IBAction in the extension). That is the thing that I can't get to work (If you control drag to a manually set .m file it doesn't work.) 
 
What does work, though, is to cntrl drag to the files owner then select the method (the  extension ones do show up).  Just tried that and I think that is the answer to my question.  Thanks

Comment: Oh I see. Yes that's what I was doing, just control-dragging to another object, not to a file. I'm not sure if it works with the file.